# Internet browser changes workspace on focus

Tags: xubuntu, workspaces, workspace-switcher

When I open a link from a document or whatever in workspace A, the browser changes from workspace X to A and opens the link in a new tab.

**How do I prevent the browser to change workspaces on focus?**

Using Firefox and Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it: `Settings > Window Manager Tweaks > Focus > Do nothing`

[image]